# Opening a Homegroup folder share prompts for password

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, network-shares, homegroup

I have two PCs, both with their own local accounts.

```
\\THINKPAD-T61P 
OS: Windows 7 Ultimate 32bit 
Username: Lappy

\\Matthew-PC
OS: Windows 7 Home Premium 64bit
Username: Matthew
```

Both of these users are on the same Homegroup, each PC can "see" each other from the Homegroup folder.

On `Matthew-PC`, I have a folder that was shared with the Homegroup (by right clicking on folder and clicking *Share With > Homegroup (Read)*).

On `THINKPAD-T61P` logged in as `Lappy`, I can see the folder I have shared on `Matthew-PC`, however when I try and open the folder to access the contents, it asks me for user credentials.

Why do I need to provide credentials of a user on the machine I'm trying to read files from?

I tested and indeed if I put in the user `Matthew` and the correct password it will give me access.  This is pointless for me as I want to be able to share files with other people without them knowing my password.

On both machines, the *Advanced sharing settings* are the default for Windows 7, but most notably, the following (defaults) are used.

- Turn on password protected sharing
- Allow Windows to manage homegroup connections (recommended)

How do I share these folders without sharing passwords?

Comment: Turn off password protected sharing?

Comment: Still asks for credentials.

Comment: Is there not a box to check to "remember these credentials"?

Comment: I don't want to use the account `Matthew` to read the shared files from the laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the `/Users` folder was not shared on each machine.  Re-creating the Homegroup fixed this.